# Regular expression used for letters not failing for dots

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
while read first last email
do
#echo "$first" "$last" "$email"
re='[a-zA-Z]+'
if [[ "$first" =~ $re && "$last" =~ $re ]]; then
        echo "$email"
else
        echo "bad"
fi
done < "$filename"
```

I am writing a bash script and trying to check the format list provided in the argument of the shell filename.File has the content as

```
Noble Able aable@ablecorp.com
Bob builder <bob_baker@bakerandsons.com>
Chris Charley  charley@bigcorp.com
Doug_douglas@maingroup.east.com
Ed Edwards edwards@inl.net.gov
kola.coe.edu Kola Jones
```

As what I expect it should give error(print bad) at the last line kola.coe.edu since it has the dot character but my result is

```
aable@ablecorp.com
<bob_baker@bakerandsons.com>
charley@bigcorp.com
bad
edwards@inl.net.gov
Jones
```

Comment: USe anchors `^[a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: Don't use comments to answer the question.

Comment: @chepner it isn't an answer, it's a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions in the `=~` construct are not anchored (unlike patterns which might have confused you: `[[ $first == +([a-zA-Z]) ]]`).

Regex matches even if a substring of the string matches it. You need to use `^` and `$` for the beginning and end of the string, respectively.

```
[[ $first =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]]
```

Comment: @PythonCobra: "Thank you" on StackOverflow is expressed by upvoting/accepting the answer.